# Sub-viewController doesn't get autorotation notifications, bug?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If I have a view (and its controller) and I override the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method so I can respond to autorotation events everything works fine and dandy.  Now if I create another viewController and add its view to the first viewController's view via:

`[firstViewController.view addSubview:secondViewController.view]`

The secondViewController's willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method isn't called.

What gives?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autorotation system doesn't work like this. Only one view controller will receive autorotation queries/events, and it's up to this view controller to inform sub controllers about the rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, glad to know I wasn't doing something wrong.